# password validation in JSON in PlayFramework

Tags: json, validation, playframework

I am trying to create a custom validation which would check that the password contains at least 1 special character and is of minimum 8 characters. I'll use it something like

```
(JsPath \ "user" \ "password").read[String] (checkPassword)
```

I expect that checkPassword will look something like

```
val checkPassword: Reads[String] = {

}
```

I am lost after this point:

1. How will the password extracted from `(JsPath \ "user" \ "password").read[String]` sent to `checkPassword`? How do I access it in `checkPassword`. Do I use 'this'? What is type of 'this'?
2. How do I return a `Reads` from `checkPassword`?

Comment: You can take a look at the default validators to figure out how to implement your own: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsConstraints.scala#L131-L140

Answer (score 0):

You can use `verifying` validation:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

def passwordChecker(password: String): Boolean = 
  (password.length() > 7) && password.contains("$")

val userReaders = (
    (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "password").read[String](verifying(passwordChecker))
  )(User)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the code. Wondering, read expects an argument of type Reads. How will `verifying` work? I believe I have seen `verifying` before in Forms. Its signature is `def verifying(error: ⇒ String, constraint: (T) ⇒ Boolean): Mapping[T]` and `def verifying(constraint: (T) ⇒ Boolean): Mapping[T]`

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsConstraints.scala#L142

or here for 2.x: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsConstraints.scala#L152